# How do you make a sentence like 'I saw the bird singing.' unambiguous?

Tags: punctuation, ambiguity

There is a sentence,

> I saw the bird singing.

I think the sentence above can have two meaning.

First meaning is ' I saw the singing bird.'
Second meaning is ' I saw the bird while I am singing.'

How can I tell the difference when I see the sentence ?

Is there any grammar?

Comment: Why do you think the sentence can have two meanings?

Comment: @Rathony: English is often ambiguous in meaning, and users will rely on context (other statements in a conversation or book) to figure out what a sentence means. In the example given by the OP, the normal meaning of "I saw the bird singing" is about a singing bird, but English allows the meaning "the viewer was singing while watching the bird". This is a non-usual meaning, but if the context was something like "I left my bed singing, I kissed my wife singing, I walked to work singing, I saw a bird singing", you could understand the last part to mean either or both were singing.

Comment: @Sina I would not call this sentence ambiguous. I think the definite article **the** plays an important role and idiomatically, the sentence is not ambiguous. In "I saw him crossing the street", who is crossing the street here?

Comment: @Rathony While he was crossing the street vs while I was... . Who knows? But the speaker! I agree with you, context helps mainly to erase the ambiguity. But at the sentence level, he can ask linguists to help him, can't he?!

Comment: @Sina We use a comma or conjunction when we need to avoid confusion or ambiguity and separate a dangling participle.

Comment: The first meaning is not *I saw the singing bird*.  A singing bird does not have to be singing when you saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you tell the difference when you see it? You rely on context. If that doesn't work, you guess.

How do you make the sentence unambiguous that the subject is doing the singing? Move *singing* closer to the subject, as in *Singing, I saw the bird.*

Unambiguous that the bird is singing? Use a relative clause, as someone else suggests:

*I saw the bird that was singing* or *I saw the bird while it sang.*

Answer (score 6):

Structurally,

I **verb**ed something **verb**ing

can indeed have two meanings:

I|we|you|he|she|it|they **verb**ed something while *it* was **verb**ing.

I|we|you|he|she|it|they **verb**ed something while *I|we|you|he|she|it|they* was|were **verb**ing.

Normally, however, we do not rely upon structure alone when making sense of a spoken utterance:

**The canary heard the cat purring.**

**I took the eye exam standing.**

In general, it is the cat who purrs, not the canary. Eye exams do not stand; the person does.

But sometimes the sentence will be ambiguous:

**I watched him die laughing.**

A native speaker *listening* to another native speaker will often be able to disambiguate from prosodic cues such as syntactic micropauses and intonational differences. But when seeking to make sense of a *written* statement of this type, we cannot do so in isolation. We need **context**, provided by the statement itself, by the situation at hand, and by other statements in vicinity.

Punctuation, as has been remarked, will often be used to indicate or signal the  prosodic contours that would disambiguate the utterance in speech.

I watched him die, laughing.  (I was laughing).

I watched him die laughing.  (He was laughing).

Answer (score 1):

No, "I saw the bird singing" means "I saw the bird while the bird was singing". It would not be understood to mean that the speaker was singing. If you wanted to say that, you'd have to say, "I saw the bird while I was singing" or "Singing, I saw the bird".

Comment: How about "I noticed him dancing." Does this sentence have two meaning?

Comment: I agree with you Jay. "I saw the bird while singing" is another option - I think most people would interpret that as "while *I* was singing", not "while *it* was singing".

Comment: @ nnnnnn Jay While I was singing vs while it was singing ;)

Comment: @nnnnnn sina Yes, quite true.

Comment: @박용현 "I noticed him dancing." Only one meaning: "he" was dancing. Again, if you wanted to say that you were dancing, you could say, "I noticed him while I was dancing" or "When I was dancing, I noticed him." (Many other possible ways to express the idea, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply reword the following:

> I saw the bird singing.

Into this:

> I saw the bird that was singing.

Or even:

> I saw the singing bird.